# How to create concatenated list in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I have two lists of String, one comes from the right sub-tree of a node and another one comes from left sub-tree of that node. Each string in either of the list is actually a comma separated list of ints.

Now I need to create a new list that has:

- the value of root *v* at the start
- followed by a comma
- followed by a string picked from leftList
- followed by a comma
- followed by a string picked form rightList

So, if rightList has:

- `1,2,3,4,5`, and
- `1,4,5,2,3`

and the leftList has:

- `7,8,6,98,12`, and
- `7,98,12,8,6`

and the value at node is `10`, the output list should be:

- `10,7,8,6,98,12,1,2,3,4,5`,
- `10,7,8,6,98,12,1,4,5,2,3`,
- `10,7,98,12,8,6,1,2,3,4,5`,
- `10,7,98,12,8,6,1,4,5,2,3`,
- `10,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,6,98,12`,
- `10,1,2,3,4,5,7,98,12,8,6`,
- `10,1,4,5,2,3,7,8,6,98,12`,
- `10,1,4,5,2,3,7,98,12,8,6`.

It is not difficult for me to implement using the traditional *for-each*, *for* or *while* loop. In fact, here is one implementation:

```
public ArrayList<String> getList (Node n) {

    //Prepare leftList and rightList...

    if (leftList.size() == 0) return prepareSingleList(sb, v, rightList);
    if (rightList.size() == 0) return prepareSingleList(sb, v, leftList);

    //TODO: re-write this code to use Stream API

    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    //both lists are non-empty, so run two loops    
    for (String l: leftList) {
        for(String r: rightList) {
            sb.setLength(0);
            appendValues(v, l, r, sb);
            myList.add(sb.toString());
            sb.setLength(0);
            appendValues(v, r, l, sb);
            myList.add(sb.toString());
        }
    }
    return myList;
}

private void appendValues(int v, String s1, String s2, StringBuilder sb) {
    sb.append(v);
    sb.append(",");
    sb.append(s1);
    sb.append(",");
    sb.append(s2);
}
```

---

**Question:** I'm trying to understand streams API and lambda expressions in Java-8. How do I re-write the code written after `//TODO:...` part in my code above using Stream API?

Comment: You're doing all that the wrong way. What you're calling lists are actually comma-separeted strings. But they **should be** lists. Only transform the lists to strings at the very last moment, when you need to print them.

Comment: @JBNizet: I understand the optimization you are suggesting. The run time will become O(n^2) because of proactive string concatenation at lower levels. My focus here is on understanding the Stream API. Is it necessary to have lists for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a `List<String>leftList`, and a `List<String> rightList`. And you want to generate all the pairs of elements from `leftList` and `rightList`, using the Stream API.

This would be more readable, IMO, with two nested loops, but you can use flatMap to achieve the same result:

```
leftList.stream()
        .flatMap(left -> rightList.stream()
                                  .map(right -> left + "," + right))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to have the pairs in the two directions, you can just do

```
leftList.stream()
        .flatMap(left -> rightList.stream()
                                  .flatMap(right -> Stream.of(left + "," + right, 
                                                              right + "," + left))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But, as already indicated in the comments, representing everything as a String is counter-productive. If you instead had a Pair class containing both elements, instead of a String concatenation, you could just iterate twice on the list of pairs, and display it once with the left node on the left, and once with the left node on the right.

Comment: You're missing a `map(s -> v + "," + s)` I think also to prepend the value to each string.

Comment: Indeed. I left that part as a trivial exercise for the OP :-)